# Extreme speed difference of reading a small file between fgets and fread in php, why?

Tags: php

**Question:** Why is it that fgets with feof and echo is nearly 9 seconds slower than using just fread, or file_get_contents? Even when the file is literally 12 lines long and less than 1kb in memory.

**Additional info:** 
This is the fgets operation I am using to read files taken directly from IBM:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-readfiles/

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   echo $line;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

And this is the other code I am using to read from the file:

```
$articleInner = fread($file, filesize($file));  // Read Entire File;
$data =  explode("\n", $articleInner);
foreach( $data as $info ) // looping through read data.
{
```

The differences in speed between these two is so large! But what truly baffles me is that if the first block of code reads just 10 lines it literally takes at least 10 seconds. That doesn't seem very practical to me at all.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's also a big difference in memory usage between the two: the first uses a lot less memory... but if all you're doing is reading and echoing, then neither of your pieces of code will be as fast as readfile()

Comment: @AmalMurali Question Updated.

Comment: @MarkBaker well, it's not exactly just reading the entire file and echoing all of it. I have a segment of the files set up as a "preview" of the entire file. I'll post what the file looks like in the additional info.

Comment: The first block of code executes 12 reads against the file (one for each line) each of which is a "slow" disk IO function; the second only executes a single "slow" disk IO request: that's why the difference in speed... you might wonder why people don't always use the fast method: the answer is memory usage, especially when working with larger files. The first method only ever has one line in memory at a time, the second loads the whole file into memory; and memory is typically a precious resource in PHP because it is restricted

Comment: Wow, that clears things up quite a bit. Thanks Mark!

Comment: Also output (using `echo`) is also draining on I/O. Buffering the output can help here, see PHP output control functions and configuration.